# Erlang XML parsing

Tags: json, xml, erlang

Задача сделать xml конвертор.
Столкнулся с проблемой проверки есть ли в атрибутах секция CDATA.

сейчас весь xml документ я конвертирую в erlang term таким образом:

```
-module(xmlencoder).

-export([input/1]).

input(Xml) -> 
    {ok, Elem, _Tail} = erlsom:simple_form(Xml),
    parse(Elem).

parse({Node, [], [Value]}) when is_list(Value) ->
    [{Node, Value}];
parse({Node, [], Children}) ->
    V = children_to_struct(Children, []),
    [{Node, V}];
parse({Node, Attributes, Children}) ->
    V = attributes_to_struct(Attributes, []) ++ children_to_struct(Children, []),
    [{Node, V}].

children_to_struct([], Acc) -> Acc;
children_to_struct([Value], Acc) when is_list(Value) ->
    Acc ++ [{"#text", Value}];
children_to_struct([Value | T], Acc) when is_tuple(Value) ->
    children_to_struct(T, Acc ++ parse(Value)).

attributes_to_struct([], Acc) -> Acc;
attributes_to_struct([{K, V}|T], Acc) ->
    attributes_to_struct(T, Acc ++ [{"@" ++ K, V}]).
```

Подскажите как можно добавить проверку на секцию CDATA или подскажите в каком направлении смотреть?

в идеале хочу получить терм, который смогу сконвертировать в json такого вида(кусок с CDATA):

XML на входе:

```
<foo id="6587"><![CDATA[<tag>Some text</tag>]]>​</foo>
```

JSON на выходе:

```
"foo": {
"@id": "6587",
"#cdata-section": "<tag>Some text</tag>"
},
```

Comment: могу только посоветовать искать библиотеку с поддержкой такого XML-формата. `erlsom` может зафиксировать CDATA, но распознать - нет.

Comment: @GreenDragon да erlsom оборачивает его нормально в лист ["<tag>Some text</tag>"]. По идее проверку на тэг CDATA нужно делать до парсинга.